# Enable file and folder selection in HTML form with webkitdirectory

Tags: html, forms, input, webkitdirectory

Is there any way to enable BOTH - **file selection** and also **folder selection** with HTML forms?
Currently one or the other does work, I can't seem to be able to use both in single input statement.

If it's not possible to combine both types in single input, what would be most standard way to allow user upload both types with single action?

```html
<p>Selecting ONLY directories
    <input name="directory" type="file" webkitdirectory multiple>
</p>
<p>Selecting ONLY files
    <input name="files" type="file" multiple>
</p>
```

Comment: You can't select a folder

Comment: Be honest - you haven't run the example - did you ? ;) \Clearly you can.